# PL/SQL procedure to cascade delete child tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a situation like this.

I have to write a PL/SQL procedure to delete ALL child tables of a parent table and modify the length of the column which was referenced in the child table.

I need to take input from the user these parameters.
parent table name
parent column name (whose column size is to be altered )
new column size

I am new to PL/SQL programming .Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try something? At least building a block with basics?

Comment: Do you just want to empty the child tables (so you can make the column smaller) or do you want to drop them?

Comment: @ammoQ i want to drop the child tables and alter the parent table colun size input by the user

Comment: @realspirituals i have tried writing some modules but they are for specific cases and i want to general cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do your job here, but these hints should help you:

- Find the name of the primary key constraint of the parent table in `all_cons_columns` where `table_name='*name of the parent table*' and column_name='*name of the column you want to alter*'`
- Find the child tables in `all_conststraints` where `constraint_type='R' and r_constraint_name='*name of the primary key constraint found in step one*'`
- Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute the DML statements to drop the child tables and alter the parent table